# Cordova vibation, can't get cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to make the most simple kind of cordova app for android but I can't make it work. I'm using phonegap to create an app with only one button that you click and the phone should vibrate. But of course it doesn't work.

I'm using `cordova-plugin-vibration` and all seem fine. Looking at the console the error message I get is `GET http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxxx/www/cordova.js`.

cordova.js is located in the `platform/android/assets/lib` like it should, but it still doesn't work. What might be the reason?

edit***

Here is the code I'm using:

html:

```
<body>
    <main>            
       <button id = "vibration">SHAKE IT</button>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

js:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById("vibration").addEventListener("click", vibration);
    },
function vibration() {
    var time = 3000;
    navigator.vibrate(time);
}
```

/Håkan

ps. I'm new to this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try creating deviceready event listener in body onload function and invoke the plugin code inside deviceready function.

Comment: Check out this link for more info - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#page-toc-source

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your index.html you include cordova like this:

```
<script src="www/cordova.js"></script>
```

If so, try changing it to

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If not, it may help if you would show a bit more of your code ;)

Comment: it was already the second option but non of the two works. I have included the code now...

Comment: Do you still get the same error? Are you running it in an emulator?

Comment: I run it in Android studio emulator, but it's impossible to get the vibrations there. The error message is when running it in Chrome. Ive also uploaded the whole project to a server to test on a phone, but it doesn't vibrate.

Comment: Cordova only gets included in the built application... It doesn't work in the browser, returning a 404 not found message

Comment: Ok. Make sense. But it doesn't work on my device either. Because testing vibrations in the emulator doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Does your vibrate-function fire? And is navigator.vibrate defined? What should it look like, when your emulator vibrates? Did you try it on a real device already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113832/discussion-between-hakan-and-argee).